# Google Calendar API Freebusy request: combine response for multiple calendars?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

For example, currently with the following request structure:

```
{
  "timeMin": "2018-04-15T07:00:00.000Z",
  "timeMax": "2018-04-16T07:00:00.000Z",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "cal1_id"
    },
    {
      "id": "cal2_id"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would get a response something like this:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#freeBusy",
 "timeMin": "2018-04-15T07:00:00.000Z",
 "timeMax": "2018-04-16T07:00:00.000Z",
 "calendars": {
  "cal1_id": {
   "busy": [
    {
     "start": "2018-04-16T01:00:00Z",
     "end": "2018-04-16T02:00:00Z"
    },
    {
     "start": "2018-04-16T04:00:00Z",
     "end": "2018-04-16T05:00:00Z"
    }
   ]
  },
  "cal2_id": {
   "busy": [
    {
     "start": "2018-04-16T02:00:00Z",
     "end": "2018-04-16T03:00:00Z"
    },
    {
     "start": "2018-04-16T04:00:00Z",
     "end": "2018-04-16T05:00:00Z"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

**Notice:**

1. The freebusy info is separated by calendar
2. In cal1 there is an event from 1-2am and in cal2 there is an event from 2-3am.
3. There is a duplicate time of 4-5am in each one.

**What I would like:**

1. A single list of busy ranges. Which calendars belong to which busy range is not necessary, but could be useful.
2. The 1-2am and 2-3am events in separate calendars would look like a single 1-3am busy range.
3. The 4-5am events in both calendars would return a single 4-5am busy range.

The [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query) describes `items` as a `List of calendars and/or **groups** to query.` What do they mean by **groups**? Can I make a single item that is a group of calendars? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Would also like to know if you found out what they meant by "groups"